# Function in a loop over dataset

Tags: r, function, loops

So I´m having difficulties getting a function to work over several years. 
The function looks like this:

```
minusgompakll1=function(s,ll,n,z)
{

 #  Computes minus log-likelihood function under the Gomperz-Makeham model.
 #  Historical data are defined by three equally long vectors "ll", "n" and "z"
 #  where "ll" defines the age of the individuals, "n" the number of them per
 #  age and "z" the number of deaths.
 #
 #  Output is minus the log-likelihood function under "s=log(theta)"
 #  where "theta" is the vector of Gomper-Makeham parameters.

 t=exp(s)
 p=exp(-t[1]-t[2]*exp(t[3]*ll))
 -sum((n-z)*log(p)+z*log(1-p))
 }
```

The "s" parameter is a constant one, "ll" is a vector that will go from 18-100 (years), "n" is the number of individuals exposed to risk, while "z" is the number of deaths.

Now, to compute this function over a single year is no problem. However, my dataset runs from year 1940-1979, with estimates for every single age (18-100). So in each year, say year 1940, we have estimates for age 18-100. Then after estimates for age 100, the dataset continues to year 1941, with age 18 again. A preview of how "n" looks like:

```
       Year Age   Female     Male    Total
 18889 1940  18 22096.83 23138.00 45234.83
 18890 1940  19 22031.17 23127.33 45158.50
 18891 1940  20 21978.83 23120.00 45098.83
 18892 1940  21 21967.50 23119.83 45087.33
 18893 1940  22 21896.17 23058.83 44955.00
 18894 1940  23 21876.17 23011.00 44887.17
 18895 1940  24 21774.67 22933.33 44708.00
 18896 1940  25 21676.00 22804.33 44480.33
 18897 1940  26 21355.83 22550.33 43906.17
 18898 1940  27 21346.50 22519.00 43865.50
 18899 1940  28 21367.83 22481.50 43849.33
 18900 1940  29 21368.33 22490.50 43858.83
 18901 1940  30 21390.50 22435.67 43826.17
 18902 1940  31 21335.00 22433.00 43768.00
 18903 1940  32 21378.00 22476.00 43854.00
 18904 1940  33 21401.00 22516.83 43917.83
 .
 .
 23228 1979  28 29775.00 30259.33 60034.33
 23229 1979  29 30518.33 31344.00 61862.33
 .
 .
 23299 1979  99       NA       NA       NA
 23300 1979 100       NA       NA       NA
```

So it is a pretty large dataset. The "z" paramater is almost the same, only with the number of deaths, for both Male and Female. My task is to use the function, over all of these estimates, and then for example plot them in the end. I tried with a for-loop like this:

```
X = vector()
for(i in exposure_RISK$Year){
s=-c(8,9,2)
ll = c(18:100)[i]
n = exposure_RISK$Male[i]
z = deaths$Male[i]

X[i] = minusgompakll1(s,ll,n,z)
}
```

This only gives me dataset containing of NA´s from year 1940-1979. I´m pretty sure the problem is in "ll", where it only goes to 100, then dont start at age 18 again. Perhaps multiple problems? Can anyone indicate where the problem is, or how I get the program to work?

Thankful for every answer!

Comment: You say `ll` should be a vector from 18 to 100 but in the loop your indexing it with `i` so you will only get a single number in `ll`.  You should check the value of `ll` before your function call to make sure it is what you expect (`print(ll)`).  You may also have `NA` values because it looks like you have missing values in `n` so the `sum` call inside your function will return `NA` unless you set `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: Hmm that is true. But then "ll" will be a vector from 18-100, and "n" and "z" will contain one estimate per that vector in the function. I need to line up all three vectors so that they all are in the same agegroup, while iterating over years, that is where i dont understand how to do so @av1 :/

Comment: @Jaz, I guess what you need is to merge data sets `n` and `z` by the `Year` and `Age` criteria. The resulting set will have columns with age, deaths, and risks, and they are guaranteed to be of the same length.  Then, you can group the resulting data set by `Year` and apply `minusgompakll1` function. If it sounds like a right strategy, I can help with the code.

Comment: @MaratTalipov I now made a new dataset "df" containing "n", "z", Year and Age. How do I now group the resulting data by year? The problem is, for every Year (say 1940) i need a vector for Age(18-100), a vector for "n" (containg estimates for every age), and the same for deaths. So each iteration in the minusgompakll1-function will receive 3 vectors, each vector of size 83. Then doing this for one year, i need to move on to the next, which again will have 3 vectors of size 83 (size 83 because Age 18-100 is 83 estimates). Thank you

Comment: And the Age column goes from 18-100, then start at age 18 again for a new year

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the solution:

**Setup**

```
set.seed(1)

# Make a sample data set with risks. For simplicity, we assume there are no NAs
risk <- expand.grid(Age=18:100,Year=1940:1979)
risk$Female <- runif(nrow(risk),min=20000,max=30000)
risk$Male <- runif(nrow(risk),min=20000,max=30000)
risk$Total <- with(risk,Female+Male)

# Make a sample data set with number of deaths For simplicity, we assume there are no NAs
deaths <- expand.grid(Age=18:100,Year=1940:1979)
deaths$Female <- runif(nrow(deaths),min=1000,max=2000)
deaths$Male <- runif(nrow(deaths),min=1000,max=2000)
deaths$Total <- with(deaths,Female+Male)

# Merge risks and deaths
d <- merge(risk,deaths,by=c('Year','Age'),suffixes=c('.risk','.death'))

s <- -c(8,9,2)
```

**The actual code**

```
library(dplyr)

# Apply the function for the data set grouped by year
d %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(likelihood=minusgompakll1(s,Age,Male.risk,Male.death))
```

**Output**

```
#    Year likelihood
# 1  1940   17165333
# 2  1941   18402227
# 3  1942   16660317
# 4  1943   18288280
# 5  1944   18004813
# 6  1945   16669699
# 7  1946   16531964
# 8  1947   18000839
# 9  1948   16945135
# ...
```

Comment: That was a good setup, thanks! I tried to install the package dplyr, that could not be found? And what is "%>%" written there?

Comment: Did you do it with `install.packages('dplyr')` in R? Re: %>% -- it is a way to chain together multiple operations in `dplyr`. From the official documentation: "The functions work via simple substitution so that `x %.% f(y)` is translated into `f(x, y)`"

Comment: Yes the package now works, thanks! :)
But I still get problems with the %>% input, I get an error message:     

    df%>%
    group_by(Year) %>%
    summarise(likelihood=minusgompakll1(s,age,Male.risk,Male.death))
    Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Just to make sure -- you didn't forget to load the package (`library(dplyr)`), right?

Comment: Ahh, there it finally worked! Sees like I had an older version of the R, that did not include that package. By updating R it finally worked! Thank you Marat! :)

Comment: Hi again Marat! So I´ve tried the method u gave me, it worked, but the output only gave ut likelihood-estimates from year 1940-1949, not all the up to year 1979?

Comment: That's weird... Is there anything unusual in 1949 (NAs, missing fields, anything like that)? And, any warnings/errors?

Comment: Doesn´t show any errors. I tried both with a dataset with 0´s/NA´s, and with exluding rows containing them. The thing is, I first have to convert every NA-number to 0, or else i will only get NA´s. But by making them zero, I tried the method you gave me on this dataset, and with the dataset excluding every row containing 0. But it still only outputs the likelihood from year 1940-1949.

Comment: Ahh, finally got it right Marat. The package "dplyr" only shows 10 rows, and as many columns as the screen allows. But by specifying: 
"print(d, n=40)" it shows the whole column with all the years! :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Now it makes sense to me.